# If $f(z)$ is entire, and it is constant in $\{z:|z|\le 1\}$, then $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is entire, and it is constant in $\{z:|z|\le 1\}$, then $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{C}$?

(I'm asking this because I need to prove that a function is constant, so I wonder if I'm already done if I showed that is constant in the closed unit disk..)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; by the identity theorem, if two analytic functions $f,g$ agree on a non-discrete subset of $\mathbb C$ ;(meaning a set that contains an interval; has non-empty interior), in this case the set {$z: |z|\leq 1$} then $f=g$ in all of $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take $g(z) = c$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$, where $c$ is the constant that $f$ is equal to on the disk. Then $f - g \equiv 0$ identically on the disk, and so the set of zeros of $f - g$ has an accumulation point.

An analytic function whose set of zeros has an accumulation point is identically zero, so $f - g$ is zero on the entire plane.